# How to optimize query for optional input id (either one specific row or whole table)

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a query that is used for generating names on each node in a tree.
This method now has one input parameter (p_optional_id_node NUMBER).

My query has a condition that looks like this:

`(p_optional_id_node IS NULL OR p_optional_id_node=n.id)`

This procedure takes one minute when i use it with:

`p_optional_id_node=NULL`

and ~2 seconds if:

`p_optional_id_node=123.`

If i change the condition from:

`(p_optional_id_node IS NULL OR p_optional_id_node=n.id)`

to:

`p_optional_id_node=n.id`

it takes ~25ms.

How can i optimize a query like this to use ~25ms if i set p_optional_id to a number and ~1 minute if i set it to null?

I don't want to duplicate the logic in this method to have one procedure for each case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
WHERE NVL(p_optional_id_node, n.id) = n.id
```

Comment: This worked best of the answers i got. It's not perfect though... Original statement with input=123 executes in 2 seconds, original statement with input=NULL executes in 60 seconds. With your solution input=123 executes in 0.15sec and input=null in 400 seconds.

The most important is that update with a number is fast. The procedure will only run with NULL after an update routine (each night)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Oracle isn't using the index anymore, because of the OR. You can try to split this in two separate queries and union them:

```
select *
from mytable
where p_optional_id_node is null
union all
select *
from mytable
where p_optional_id_node = n.id;
```

The first part only select records when p_optional_id_node is NULL (it gets all records then). The second part only gets records when p_optional_id_node is not NULL (it gets all matches then). So you still get one or the other, but Oracle may now be io the mood to use the index.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return all rows in mytable in the case when p_potional_id_node is null and all records with id = p_optional_id_node otherwise then you can try following:

To do not duplicate logic in this method, you can create table-valued function or view for the main logic (select * from mytable or something else) and then with using [IF](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/controlstructures.htm#CJAJGBEE) statement in the method:

1. In a case when p_potional_id_node is null, then return select from function/view without where clause
2. In a case, when p_potional_id_node is not null, then return select from function/view with where it = p_potional_id_node

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
from mytable
where p_optional_id_node = decode(n.id, null, null, n.id);
```

Comment: This was worth a shot, but unfortunately p_optional_id_node executed in 15 seconds with this solution. Thank you for the suggestion anyways!